# Rotation around a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, rotations

I have a simple question.

Find the matrix for the rotation of $90^\circ$ counter-clockwise around the vector $v = (1,2,2)$

My first approach here was to create $3$ vectors, $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ and see how a $90^\circ$ rotation effected them. Then take the matrix of that times the vector in this question. However, that seems to be wrong.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

/John.

Comment: You can apply a basis transformation on a 'casual' rotation matrix or you can do it with Rodrigues' formula: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Comment: Equivalently, you can go into quaternion world. Advantage: no gimbal lock.

Comment: Or you could translate the vector to the origin ,  rotate $90^\circ$ then translate the vector back to it original spot

Comment: @Adrian Matrices Gimbal lock doesn't happen with matrices either, only with Euler angles.

Comment: @Lieven: Right, given an angle and vector, you can do what John Snow is asking unambiguously. In my experience, though, you're almost always going to want to invert that process, and quaternions are superior for that.

Comment: @Adrian Keister A bit off topic, but I'm not so sure. Computation wise, inverting a quaternion is a little faster (just 3 negations), while in case of the matrix, it's a transpose. On the other hand, transforming a vector by a matrix is faster than transforming it by a quaternion.

The only case where quaternions are the clear winner is when you want to interpolate between rotations.

Comment: Your approach is valid. If you ended up with the wrong answer, then you likely made a computation error along the way. If you’d like someone to point out your mistake, update your question with the details of your computation.

Answer (score 1):

With Rodrigues formula you have:

$R(v,\theta)=I+\sin(\theta)S(v)+(1-\cos(\theta))S^2(v)$

where $S(v)=\begin {bmatrix}  0 &-z &y \\ z & 0 &-x \\ -y & x &0 \end{bmatrix}$ and  $x,y,z$ are coordinates of unit vector representing axis.

In your case  $v=[1/3 \ \ \ 2/3 \ \ \ 2/3]^T$.

For angle $\pi/2$ the formula has form

$R(v,\theta)=I+ S(v)+ S^2(v)$.

Comment: For details of the formula see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation

Comment: Further simplification of the final formula for $\pi/2$ can be obtained taking into consideration that $S^2(v)=vv^T-I$. Then $R=S(v)+vv^T$ what is fast to compute..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the matrix you want by applying your rotation (in some way) to the 3 basis vectors, and use those 3 basis vectors as columns of your matrix.

Now to apply your rotation to a vector:

Normalize $v$ so that it has length 1.

The rotated version of any vector $x$ is $(x\cdot v)v + x \times v$. The first term represents the part of $x$ parallel to $v$ and isn't affected by the rotation, the second term is the part perpendicular to $v$, rotated by 90 degrees.